# Does DbSet.SqlQuery ignore column mapping? How can I get my entity from an sql query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database that I can't change. One of its tables' column names is `MFG-DATE` (with a hyphen). I made a class for the table:

```
public class tblPreNeltec
{
    [Key]
    public string LotNo { get; set; }
    //...
    [Column("MFG-DATE")]
    public DateTime? MFG_DATE {get; set; }
}
```

So I would think when I try to get `tblPreNeltec`s out of the database, it should work, right? yet when I run

```
var lots = db.tblPreNeltecSet.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM tblPreNeltec WHERE LotNo LIKE @LotNo", new SqlParameter("@LotNo", LotNo)).ToList();
```

I get an error:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CofC.Models.tblPreNeltec'. A member of the type, 'MFG_DATE', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

But it shouldn't be `MFG_DATE`! I used the `Column` attribute, it should be looking for `MFG-DATE`! Right? what am I doing wrong? And for that matter, how can I retrieve a bunch of `tblPreNeltec`s from the database by lot number, given that they have a column which has a hyphen in its name?

Comment: The mappings are not considered by `SQL` methods. Any special reason for using SQL? And if you really need to, just provide explicit columns `SELECT` clause with aliases matching the property names.